# Get uncompressed size of a .gz file in python

Tags: python, gzip

Using gzip, tell() returns the offset in the uncompressed file.
In order to show a progress bar, I want to know the original (uncompressed) size of the file.
Is there an easy way to find out?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [gzip format](http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html#header-trailer) specifies a field called `ISIZE` that:

> This contains the size of the original (uncompressed) input data modulo 2^32.

In [gzip.py](http://pydoc.org/get.cgi/usr/local/lib/python2.5/gzip.py), which I assume is what you're using for gzip support, there is a method called `_read_eof` defined as such:

```
def _read_eof(self):
    # We've read to the end of the file, so we have to rewind in order
    # to reread the 8 bytes containing the CRC and the file size.
    # We check the that the computed CRC and size of the
    # uncompressed data matches the stored values.  Note that the size
    # stored is the true file size mod 2**32.
    self.fileobj.seek(-8, 1)
    crc32 = read32(self.fileobj)
    isize = U32(read32(self.fileobj))   # may exceed 2GB
    if U32(crc32) != U32(self.crc):
        raise IOError, "CRC check failed"
    elif isize != LOWU32(self.size):
        raise IOError, "Incorrect length of data produced"
```

There you can see that the `ISIZE` field is being read, but only to to compare it to `self.size` for error detection. This then should mean that `GzipFile.size` stores the actual uncompressed size. However, I *think* it's not exposed publicly, so you might have to hack it in to expose it. Not so sure, sorry.

I just looked all of this up right now, and I haven't tried it so I could be wrong. I hope this is of some use to you. Sorry if I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I guess this is good enough. In case of a file larger than 4G, it is easy to add some heuristics to the progress bar to set the file-size to 4G + ISIZE, if tell() indicates we we are too close to ISIZE.

Comment: I need to do the same thing and I am trying to extend the GzipFile class to give the file size, but I am unsuccessful, How did you get it working?

Comment: Update: This functions works for me: http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/245777/

Comment: Note this isn't completely foolproof insofar as a gzip file that was appended to will only have the size of the last appended portion...

See:  http://pastebin.com/82zyV3k9 - the second '1000' here should actually be 2000, but it's just the size of the last block that was appended...

Comment: This value will be wrong if the uncompressed size is greater than 4GiB - [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707653/17165) shows an way to estimate it without the need to read the whole file.

Answer (score 24):

Uncompressed size is stored in the last 4 bytes of the gzip file. We can read the binary data and convert it to an int. (This will only work for files under 4GB)

```
import struct

def getuncompressedsize(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        f.seek(-4, 2)
        return struct.unpack('I', f.read(4))[0]
```

Comment: Open the file `"rb"` to avoid `error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4`.

Comment: This is exactly what is shown in old **Jorge Israel Peña**'s answer, so while your answer provides a handy function, it does not add much to the topic. Moreover, as comments say in the old answer, depending only on the last 4 bytes is actually NOT 100% foolproof, as the GZ allows you to append new blocks at end of file

Answer (score 14):

Despite what the other answers say, the last four bytes are not a reliable way to get the uncompressed length of a gzip file. First, there may be multiple members in the gzip file, so that would only be the length of the last member. Second, the length may be more than 4 GB, in which case the last four bytes represent the length modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. Not the length.

However for what you want, there is no need to get the uncompressed length. You can instead base your progress bar on the amount of *input* consumed, as compared to the length of the gzip file, which is readily obtained. For typical homogenous data, that progress bar would show exactly the same thing as a progress bar based instead on the uncompressed data.

Comment: Mark, I'm recently working on some programatic manipulation of gzip files and often see many of your answers at the bottom of the stack with one or two votes. I guess people don't recognize you. Thanks for your tremendous contributions and for contributing your answers to compression questions despite the lack of recognition.

Comment: When writting a command to import a gzipped CSV file into PostgreSQL (`rows pgimport`) I've implemented a progress bar using the amount of uncompressed data already read but also added an estimate of the total uncompressed size - if the program finds the estimate wrong, it just updates it to the total read ([this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/707653/17165) has the Python code to estimate the size beyond 4GiB).

Comment: @ÁlvaroJusten Um, why? You must know the size of the compressed file in order to attempt that estimate. In that case, simply base your progress bar on the fraction of compressed data consumed. Problem solved.

Comment: @MarkAdler I use Python's `os.stat()` to get the compressed size. I prefer to see the uncompressed size speed on progress bar because this is the amount will be inserted on the database.

Answer (score 5):

Unix way: use "gunzip -l file.gz" via subprocess.call / os.popen, capture and parse its output.

Comment: Never touch operating systems that are older than me... 
Seriously speaking: I'm looking for a python solution, as the code is for all platforms.

Comment: Windows is at least 24 or 25 years old. Version 1 came out around 1985 or so. How old are you?

Comment: 44.5 (and last used Unix at 18)

Comment: Note that this essentially dues the same thing suggested by [@Jorge Israel Peña](https://stackoverflow.com/users/101090/jorge-israel-pe%c3%b1a)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704576), and thus will not be valid for files larger than 4GB.

Answer (score 4):

The last 4 bytes of the .gz hold the original size of the file

Comment: The last 4 bytes is the “size of the original (uncompressed) input data modulo 2^32.” (http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about performance, but this could be achieved without knowing `gzip` magic by using:

```
with gzip.open(filepath, 'rb') as file_obj:
    file_size = file_obj.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)
```

This should also work for other (compressed) stream readers like `bz2` or the plain `open`.

EDIT:
as suggested in the comments, `2` in second line was replaced by `io.SEEK_END`, which is definitely more readable and probably more future-proof.

EDIT:
Works only in Python 3.

Comment: i.e. `file_size = file_obj.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)`

Comment: Python 3! No Python 2 tho! `ValueError: Seek from end not supported`.
However: struct.unpack works on 2.7!

Comment: Unfortunately, `file_obj.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)` (or `os.SEEK_END`, btw), takes a lot of time for big .GZ files with `gzip` library - does it make decompressing to get to the end of the stream?

Answer (score 1):

```
    f = gzip.open(filename)
    # kludge - report uncompressed file position so progess bars
    # don't go to 400%
    f.tell = f.fileobj.tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for the `gzip` module, I see that the underlying file object for `GzipFile` seems to be `fileobj`.  So:

```
mygzipfile = gzip.GzipFile()
...
mygzipfile.fileobj.tell()
```

?

Maybe it would be good to do some sanity checking before doing that, like checking that the attribute exists with `hasattr`.

Not exactly a public API, but...

Comment: .tell() works great. What I'm looking for is the original file size.

Answer (score 0):

GzipFile.size stores the uncompressed size, but it's only incremented when you read the file, so you should prefer len(fd.read()) instead of the non-public GzipFile.size.

Comment: What if the file is enormous?

Comment: Note that as @allyourcode suggests here, `len(df.read())` forces Python to hold the entire file in memory. For a very large file this can crash your process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Python2 version for [@norok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5218354/norok2)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45835363)

```py
import gzip, io

with oepn("yourfile.gz", "rb") as f:
    prev, cur = 0, f.seek(1000000, io.SEEK_CUR)
    while prev < cur:
        prev, cur = cur, f.seek(1000000, io.SEEK_CUR)

filesize = cur
```

Note that just like `f.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)` this is slow for large files, but it will overcome the [4GB size limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54360738) of the faster solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704576)

Answer (score -2):

```
import gzip

File = gzip.open("input.gz", "r")
Size = gzip.read32(File)
```