# Get uncompressed size uploaded files on S3 without downloading

Tags: amazon-s3

Is it possible to get the uncompressed and compressed sizes of files in an S3 bucket without downloading them?

I have about 750 compressed files varying from 650MB to 1.2 GB on S3 and I'd like to get the aggregated file sizes both compressed and uncompressed.  I could do download them and use some tool like this:

```
gzip -l *gz
```

But I'd have to download them first which seems like a lot of work to just get the total sizes.

Comment: Even if you could do `gzip -l` on the server (and maybe you can), it would not work for you. `gzip -l` will report the uncompressed size modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, since it is stored in a four-byte field at the end of the file. So if your 1.2 GB file has 4:1 compression, you will get a report of a compressed size of about 0.5 GB instead of 4.8 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Amazon S3 stores the **raw file**. It does not provide a feature to process the file.

It would be necessary to **download and analyze** the content of the file.

Think of S3 as being a **storage service**. It is highly durable and reliable but it is basically just a storage service. Anything you wish to do with the data has to be done elsewhere, just like if the data was stored on a USB disk or a NAS.

It is possible to download just a particular **range** of a file, but you'd need to know which part of the file contains information about the uncompressed size of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible to do with gzips. This is because the uncompressed size of a gzip (modulo 2^32) is stored in the [last 4 bytes of the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22348071/4760185). Using Python, this will get you what you want. Note that this will only work if your uncompressed file is smaller than 4 GB, otherwise it will be off by a multiple of 4 GB.

```
import boto3
import struct


def get_unpacked_size_s3_gz(bucket, key):
    s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

    compressed_size = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)["ContentLength"]
    last_four_bytes = s3_client.get_object(
        Bucket=bucket,
        Key=key,
        Range=f"bytes={compressed_size-4}-{compressed_size}"
    )["Body"]
    return struct.unpack("I", last_four_bytes.read(4))[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is possible, you just need to download the file partially, I used goofys (https://github.com/kahing/goofys) to mount S3 and test that and worked pretty well. They only scan partially the file, so the file is not downloaded entirely. Probably s3-fuse will work too (https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse).

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found for doing this is:

```
aws s3 cp s3://some_bucket/some_file.csv.gz - | zcat | wc -c
```

This streams the file to standard out (by specifying `-` as the destination), which is then piped to `zcat` to uncompress it, and then `wc -c` counts the bytes.

I was trying to find a way to get the uncompressed size of a gzip in s3 without having to *uncompress* it (similar to how `gzip -l` works in linux) but I still haven't figured out a way to do that. **However**, this does accomplish the task without having to *download* the file to your local storage. I think that was the goal of the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Piping the s3 command to gzip or zcat does not solve the problem because streaming the file to a local pipe uses exactly the same bandwidth as just downloading it. You may as well just download the file.

The best solution to me looks to be the python script to read the last 4 bytes, with the caveat about multiples of 4GB.

Shame that AWS have not added this as a feature. It would be easier to implement it at their end and add 'uncompressed size' as an optional output of s3 ls.

Edit: I have raised a feature request with AWS (9 Jul 2022)