# How to get uncompressed size of a > 4GB .gz file in python

Tags: python, byte, gzip

So there is [this super interesting thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1704458/469322) already about getting original size of a .gz file. Turns out the size one can get from the 4 file ending bytes are 'just' there to make sure extraction was successful. However: Its fine to rely on it IF the extracted data size is below 2**32 bytes. ie. 4 GB.

**Now IF** there are more than 4 GB of uncompressed data there must be multiple members in the .gz! The last 4 bytes only indicating the uncompressed size of the last chunk!

So how do we get the ending bytes of **the other chunks**?
[Reading the gzip specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952) I don't see a length of the

```
+=======================+
|...compressed blocks...|
+=======================+
```

Ok. Must depend on the CM - compression method. Which is probably `deflate`. Let's see [the RFC about it](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951). There [on page 11](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951#page-11) it says there is a `LEN` attribute for "Non-compressed blocks" but it gets funky when they tell about the Compressed ones ...

I can imagine something like

```
full_size = os.path.getsize(gz_path)
gz = gzip.open(gz_path)
pos = 0
size = 0
while True:
    try:
        head_len = get_header_length(gz, pos)
        block_len = get_block_length(gz, pos + head_len)
        size += get_orig_size(gz, pos + head_len + block_len)
        pos += head_len + block_len + 8
    except:
        break
print('uncompressed size of "%s" is: %i bytes' % (gz_path, full_size)
```

But how to `get_block_length`?!? :|

This was probably never intended because ... "stream data". But I don't wanna give up now.
One big bummer already: **Even 7zip** shows such a big .gz with the exact uncompressed size of just the very last 4 bytes.

Does someone have another idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, no, there do not need to be multiple members. There is no limit on the length of a gzip member. If the uncompressed data is more than 4 GB, then the last four bytes simply represents that length modulo 2<sup>32</sup>. A gzip file with more than 4 GB of uncompressed data is in fact very likely to be a single member.

Second, the fact that you can have multiple members is true even for small gzip files. The uncompressed data does not need to be more than 4 GB for the last four bytes of the file to be useless.

The only way to reliably determine the amount of uncompressed data in a gzip file is to decompress it. You don't have to write the data out, but you have to process the entire gzip file and count the number of uncompressed bytes.

Comment: Ahh the modulo! I see! As the 4 bytes are only for internal checks that + crc is enough, right? I overread the modulo and thought as an int from 4 bytes can only indicate max 4GB ...
well thats sad.

Answer (score 4):

I'm coming here to leave an estimate of what you are looking for. The good answer is the one given by Mark Adler: the only reliable way to determine the uncompressed size of a gzip file is by actually decompressing it.

But I'm working with an estimate that will usually give good results, but it can fail at the boundaries. The assumptions are:

- there is only one stream in the file
- the stream have a similar compression ratio compared to the whole file

The idea is to get the compression ratio of the beginning of the file (get a 1M sample, decompress and measure), use it to extrapolate the uncompressed size from the compressed size, and finally, substitute the 32 least significant bits by the size module 32 obtained from the gzip stream.
The caveat comes at the multiple of 4GiB boudaries, as it could over/underestimate the size and give an estimate +/-4GiB displaced.

The code would be:

```
from io import SEEK_END
import os
import struct
import zlib

def estimate_uncompressed_gz_size(filename):
    # From the input file, get some data:
    # - the 32 LSB from the gzip stream
    # - 1MB sample of compressed data
    # - compressed file size
    with open(filename, "rb") as gz_in:
        sample = gz_in.read(1000000)
        gz_in.seek(-4, SEEK_END)
        lsb = struct.unpack('I', gz_in.read(4))[0]
        file_size = os.fstat(gz_in.fileno()).st_size

    # Estimate the total size by decompressing the sample to get the
    # compression ratio so we can extrapolate the uncompressed size
    # using the compression ratio and the real file size
    dobj = zlib.decompressobj(31)
    d_sample = dobj.decompress(sample)

    compressed_len = len(sample) - len(dobj.unconsumed_tail)
    decompressed_len = len(d_sample)

    estimate = int(file_size * decompressed_len / compressed_len)

    # 32 LSB to zero
    mask = ~0xFFFFFFFF

    # Kill the 32 LSB to be substituted by the data read from the file
    adjusted_estimate = (estimate & mask) | lsb

    return adjusted_estimate
```

Workarounds around the stated caveats could be to check the difference between estimate and adjusted estimate, and if bigger than 2GiB, add/substract 4GiB accordingly. But at the end, it will be always an estimate, not a reliable number.

Comment: Very cool! Thanks a lot! I'm wondering: One could probably also measure on the go while decompressing, refining the estiate.

Comment: Sure, you can keep two counters: compressed size and uncompressed size, and as they get close to the whole file, the estimate will be better and better. The point in this code is to get an estimate of the size without having to decompress everything, just a small sample. But for applications where you have to decompress anyways and you are interested in the final size for any reason, that could work. Although for estimating decompression time, tracking compressed data is enough.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Poshi for the interesting solution, but I've found this to be quite far off from reality for gzip files I've been dealing with.
To start with, above code needs two corrections - instead "import pack" use "import struct" and line "estimate = file_size * decompressed_len / compressed_len" needs to be changed to "estimate = int(file_size * decompressed_len / compressed_len)"

With that, if I run it against my gzip which decompresses to 20898119680 Bytes, this solution yields only 12308185088 Bytes, so a bit more than half...

The last 4 bytes (variable lsb in above code) reads back as 0xDDA00000. If you convert the actual size of 20898119680 to hex you get 0x4DDA00000, which makes it obvious why the size got truncated so much. The right thing to do for files with an uncompressed size of > 4 GB is still to actually decompress...

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! You are right, I don't know how I missed the obvious pack<->struct swap and the fact that I need an integer, not a float, if I'm going to do bit manipulation. I updated the answer with your corrections.

Comment: If your files give this kind of results is because it fails one of the assumptions I'm doing: not all your data compress in a similar way. It looks like your data is hard to compress in the beginning, but easier to compress after the first megabyte.
You can try to use a bigger portion of input data for the estimate by changing the `1000000` of bytes read to a bigger number, it will take more time, but it should give you a better estimate.

Comment: Also, if your files are made with bgzip and you have the index, you can get the exact size quite easily just by reading a couple numbers.

Comment: But if the first half of your file is hard to compress and the second half is easy to compress... then you are doomed. You would have to read more than half of your file to get a better estimate, and that would be comparable to reading the whole file. And the whole point of this estimate is to avoid reading large chunks of the data to get the uncompressed file size :-(

Comment: 20898119680==0x4DDA00000 and 12308185088==0x2DDA00000. If the estimate from the extrapolation fo the first MB were close to the real uncompressed size, it would had been something like 0x4????????, which or-ed with 0xDDA00000 would have yield the correct solution.