# How to get size of uncompressed gzip file using flate2

Tags: rust, gzip, deflate, inflate, miniz

I want the *uncompressed* size of a gzipped file using rust crate [`flate2`](https://crates.io/crates/flate2).

How do I ask a `GzDecoder` or `MultiGzDecoder` for the uncompressed file size ***without* reading the entire file**?

I'm hoping for a simple function call like `header.filesz()`:

```rust
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;

extern crate flate2;
use flate2::read::GzDecoder;

fn main() -> {
    let file1 = File::open("file1.gz").unwrap();
    let mut decoder = GzDecoder::new(file1);
    let header = decoder.header().unwrap();
    let filesz = header.filesz();
}
```

Comment: What you're asking might not be possible, see this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54360738/429972

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. You need to read the whole file.