# I can't understand why my program is killed in middle reading a gzip file from S3 amazon

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip

I'm going to read a gzip file from s3 amazon. It works fine for other files (around 300 MB) but the new file is bigger (600 MB) and it is killed in the middle of the reading file.
I wonder if my code is optimum and good enough?
(the Linux server is an EC2 with 16GB RAM)

```
import boto3
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_object = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=bucket, key=filename)
path = BytesIO(s3_object.get()['Body'].read())
df = pd.read_parquet(path)
```

Comment: Can you estimate how big the file is when it's uncompressed? Is the machine maybe out of memory? Or some other memory-related limit reached?

Comment: I save it into S3 from the same EC2 instance. I'm pretty sure it's much less than 16 GB

Comment: Don't guess, verify : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22348071/562769

Comment: It's 827474256. It has the same value for smaller files!

Comment: Furthermore, Since I saved it from the same EC2, it has to be less than the memory size.

Comment: @MartinThoma it's a parquet file, there's no reason to think it'd have the gzip size header at the end